# How to set the space between lines in a div without setting line height

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing elements with display set to inline-block. These contained elements have various heights. The resulting lines in the div have various heights, according to the heights of the elements in them. This is as I want it. But I want to add some space between the lines in the div. For example, elements in adjacent lines with background color set should have a visible gap between them. The common advice for a paragrpah is to set line-height, but this sets the same height for all lines in the div, which I don't want. Is there a way to set a space between the lines without making all the lines the same height and without modifying the contained elements?

In a simplified form the HTML content looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;...">variable stuff</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;...">variable stuff</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;...">variable stuff</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;...">variable stuff</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Each inner div has different content: different height and width.

I can style all the inner divs. Pragmatically, I have already done that and have a result I could live with. But I was surprised to see that CSS doesn't have an obvious way to set line spacing (i.e. the space between lines, as opposed to the height of lines: I know about line-height but it is not, directly, line spacing and has the (undesired in this instance) effect of making all the lines the same height - even the lines where all the elements in the line have a low height). I am curious to know if there is a way to set line spacing as a parameter of the outer div, without setting the line height.

I think of it as line spacing, but another way to think of it is top and bottom margin on each line in the outer div, rather than on the outer div as a whole, and without overriding the top and bottom margins of all the inner divs (which is what I have done for now) or making all the lines the same height (as line-height does).

The only way I can think of to do it without overriding the margins of the inner divs, is by wrapping each in another div, simply to set a common margin. If I do it this way, the margins of the two divs don't collapse, which I can live with. This works well enough in this case, where all the content is divs, but it wouldn't work if I had mixed text and divs (i.e. text interspersed with divs), in which case I would be back to wishing I could find a way to specify line spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can only be done using `margin` style. You don't need to wrap each contained `DIV`s with another `DIV`. Just use the `STYLE` tag.

Here's an example. Border and colorings are added for demo purpose.

```
<style>
    #container     {width:30ex; outline:1px solid black; padding:0 .2em; background:white;}
    #container>div {display:inline-block; margin:.2em 0; background:#fca;}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div style="height:1em">variable</div>
    <div style="height:5em">variable stuff variable</div>
    <div style="height:2em">variable stuff</div>
    <div style="height:1em">variable</div>
    <div style="height:3em">variable stuff variable stuff</div>
    <div style="height:1em">variable</div>
    <div style="height:1em">variable</div>
    <div style="height:1em">variable</div>
    <div style="height:1em">variable</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can also be done with `border` too, but `margin` is more simpler.

Comment: Style the inner divs is what I have done and, with variations as to what to style (margin, border or padding) is what Jay, grillp and bkizer1 have all recommended. I searched many hours and didn't find any indication of a direct control over line spacing, as opposed to line height, so I guess this is it. Jay provided a nice example, so I marked this the answer, but thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try CSS margin or border settings on your P elements?

Comment: I am hoping not to have to re-write all the contained elements. Margin and border applied to the containing div do not affect the spacing between the lines in the div.

Comment: Sorry.. Just edited my answer.. the 'p' did not show up.. I am assuming that your DIV contains a bunch of paragraphs?

Comment: Sorry, no paragraphs (they can't contain a block element, even if the contained block element has display set to inline-block). I have added an example and further explanation to the example, as it seems I didn't make myself very clear - sorry for that.

Comment: So unless you can target the inner DIVs somehow with css selectors (class on inner div, class or id on outer div) it will be hard to target the inner divs.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the css padding property?  For Example:

```
padding:25px;
```

You can also specify:  padding-right, padding-bottom, etc.

Comment: I tried adding padding to the outer div, but it makes not difference to the gap between lines within the div. I could re-write all the contained elements, but I am hoping there is a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Whats about to use columns with inline-block and in each column are more divs.

```
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div>variable stuff</div>
    <div>variable stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div>variable stuff</div>
    <div>variable stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```