# How to give line spacing without using line-height property?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample text in my application : `"welcome to stack over flow and welcome again"`. I am using this text and because of other elements, half of the text is coming down like this:

```
                       "welcome to stack over 
                       flow and welcome again"
```

Now I need to give a space between these two lines.
This can be achieved with the "line-height" property, but it would effect other elements too.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far; it makes it easier for us to help you. Thanks

Comment: use line-height and then fix the other elements accordingly

Comment: Make a class with line-height you want and apply it to that section of text with <span> tags.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714721/how-to-set-the-space-between-lines-in-a-div-without-setting-line-height?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use element specific `line-height`. So it won't affect other elements.

**HTML**

```
<span class="text">
welcome to stack over    
flow and welcome again
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
 line-height:1; /*Global line height*/
}

.text {
 line-height:1.5; /*Element specific line height*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text is going to remain same then you can use break or can also use the text in two different tags. But using line-height will be better option as it will work even when text is changed.